# Wordpress PHP if statement to detect URL and server specific header.php page

Tags: php, wordpress, post

In WordPress I would like to to show a custom header.php if the URL contains a specific string (in this case /support/ also to include /support/forums/).  I have looked around and have tried many different combinations, but cannot seem to get it to work.  Below is the code I have, any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 5) !== 'support') {
get_header('XXXXXX');
} else {
get_header();
}
```

FYI... I need it to work this way (I think) because I am using custom post types and therefore cannot use standard WordPress calls because it is just a slug and not a Post/Category/.etc.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Another very similar way would be:

```
<?php $uri_segments = explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
if ( in_array('support', $uri_segments) ) { get_header('xxxx'); }else{ get_header(); }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget your code? Nothing is showing up.

Anyways `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is the value you are after, you can then use PHP's string manipulating functions like `explode()` or better yet `strpos()` to find and react to whatever you are after, find more about the function [explode PHP Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [strpos PHP Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and about [the _SERVER reserved variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: NO, I had keep the <?php part in and it didn't show the code, corrected that, the code should be show now.

Comment: @unkownf, if he weren't using mod_rewrite the URI would did look like `index.php?param1=support&param2=forums` and you would be right about QUERY_STRING, but after mod_rewrite does its job, that URI no longer exists, PHP will only see `/support/forums` and so the right variable to call would be REQUEST_URI.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your URI has the 'support' string always at that position (first), your code looks fine, I can't see any error there. But remember that the argument of the [get_header()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) function is the suffix that you must append to the file name. So, if you have:

```
get_header('test');
```

Your header file should be named: `header-test.php`

Also, to be sure you always find the string even if it changes position in the URI, you could do it like this:

```
$params= explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

if(in_array('support', $params)) {
    get_header('support');
} else {
    get_header();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The length of the compared string, **support** is not 5 characters long, so the if statement is always false.
2. The URI normally starts with a **/** at position 0, so include it in the string to compare or start comparing at position 1.

I would use:

```
if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 9) !== '/support/') {
```